# Excel macro to normalize data

Tags: vba, excel, normalize

I am currently trying to create a macro for Excel in which a column containing certain values (numbers basically) will be displayed in a new column in a normalized way (highest number = 1, lowest number = 0).

Usually, I would just use the formula:

```
=(J2-MIN($J$2:$J$XXX))/(MAX($J$2:$J$XXX)-MIN($J$2:$J$XXX))
```

However, as the length of the column is dynamic and will change for each set of values, I cannot enter a value for XXX.

Now, I found out how to have a dynamic range (e.g.: `numRows = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count`) but I did not manage to merge both functions.

I found a thread already in this site about normalization of data but I think it was a bit of a different story and this one here should be simpler.

I would appreciate any help! As I just started working with macros (2h ago) I would also appreciate if this will be in simple language.

EDIT:
First of all, thanks for the quick reply!

I naively tried making it work with this code:

```
Sub Normalize_TEST()
'
' Normalize_TEST Makro
'

'
    Range("A1").Select
    numRows = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Range("K2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(("J2")-MIN($J$2:$J$numRows$))/((MAX($J$2:$J$numRows$)-MIN($J$2:$J$numRows$))
    Range("K2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 11), Cells(numRows, 11))
End Sub
```

But it is not working and I get an error message ("error of compiling").

Comment: Normalization of data can mean several different things, and this just looks like like you want a formula.  Also, because simple `MIN` and `MAX` functions don't calculate as arrays, you can just use a whole column reference to achieve the result you want simply and without VBA: `=(J2-MIN($J:$J))/(MAX($J:$J)-MIN($J:$J))`  If that doesn't work for you, we're really gonna need sample data and expected results.

Comment: Also, this is tagged as VBA and you clearly mention some VBA specific coding.  Can you please edit your post to include your code so far? It will go a long way to getting help if you show your work.

Answer (score 0):

I just realize now that you are absolutely right, I don't even need VBA. Your line of =(J2-MIN($J:$J))/(MAX($J:$J)-MIN($J:$J)) works fine. I wasn't aware that with $j:$J it realizes to not include empty cells. 
I simply used this code now for cell K2 and then did a VBA autofill function for the rest.
I think this can be closed.

Thank you @tigeravatar for your super quick help!